# RegEx to find asterisk (only if not surrounded by numbers)

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a Regex expression to return a match if any of the following are true:

- An asterisk is found that isn't in the middle of 2 numbers. The first number will always be an integer but the second number could be an integer (1*4), float (8*1.35), or scientific (8*2e-3)
- Any text lines (again, ignoring scientific notation)

Note: I have built an expression to strip out any text that follows a double-asterisk ("**") but would appreciate if the solution could also incorporate that as a single step. I will eventually split the line by the values in it, but am hung up on the initial "has_text" step (flagging lines with an asterisk but ignoring when it occurs between 2 numbers):

**Sample input:**

```
input = ["1 2 3",
         "4 5 6 **This is a comment to strip",
         "123 *This is a line to ignore 321",
         "7e-1 3*8 9"]
```

**Desired output:**

```
output = ["1 2 3",
          "4 5 6",
          "7e-1 3*8 9"]
```

**Code:**

```
import re
output = []
for line in input:
    line_no_comments = re.sub('(\*{2}.*)', '', line)
    has_text = re.search('([^0-9eE .-]+[*]{1})', line_no_comments)
    if not has_text:
        output.append(line_no_comments)
```

Comment: Is this a comprehensive list of examples? It looks like you just need to ignore "lines" that begin with  `*` or strip out the rest of the line if there is a `**`?

Comment: Changed "input" to reflect case where "*" doesn't occur at start of line (which can sometimes be encountered in my dataset)

Comment: Where does this data come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested list comprehension to solve this problem - the first step being to strip comments (everything including and after `**`) and then removing any line that has a `*` preceded by or followed by a non-digit:

```
output = [x for x in [re.sub(r'\s*\*\*.*$', '', y) for y in input] if not re.search(r'(^|\D)\*|\*(\D|$)', x)]
print(output)
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
['4 5 6', '1 2 3 4', '7e-1 3*8 9']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! As a follow-up, would it be possible to expand the '3*8' to '8 8 8' in the same step? (I had been planning to do a manual loop to accomplish that but it seems that there's probably a more 'pythonic' way to do it)

Comment: @KKB you could add another step `output = [re.sub(r'(\d+)\*(\d+)\s', lambda m: (m.group(2) + ' ') * int(m.group(1)), x) for x in output]`

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression that you want should consider four cases:

1. Starting with a number, an optional space, and **no** digit after the `*`
2. Starting with a `*`
3. Match any `*` with no digit before it
4. Match any `*` with no digit behind it

Then you would just match anything after the *matched* `*`

Use the following regular expression, and `replace` the matches with *blank*

```
((^(\d+)\s?\*\D)|(^\*)|(\*(?=\D))|(\*\D)).*
```

---

Consider the following items in the list:

```
*1 2 3 This is a comment
1 *This is a comment
4 5 6 **This is a comment to strip
1 2 3 4
123 *This is a line to ignore 321
7e-1 3*8 9
```

The following lines are what the regular expression would highlight:

```
*1 2 3 This is a comment
1 *This is a comment
**This is a comment to strip
123 *This is a line to ignore 321
```

Comment: This still trips up on the "123 *This is a line to ignore 321" line. To clarify: I would like to remove that entire line (and the current solution would retain the leading "123")

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I didn't realize that you would like to realize the entire line and not leave the 123. So, if there is only 1 Number before the `*` you would like to remove it ?

Comment: Alright, issue resolved hopefully. Let me know if I missed anything please.

Comment: In the case of `**` you want to strip the comment, and in the case of `*` you want to remove the whole line? If yes then I need to fix my Regex, please let me know